# How I find the checkbox by id and apply attribute on string using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a following html string of `contentString`:

```
var content = 
   '<div id="content">' +                        
    '<div>' +
      '<input name="tBox" id="select" type="checkbox" value="" '+
      'onclick="changeView()"> Select for operation' +
      '<p style="text-align:right"><a href="#">View details</a></p>' +
    '</div>' +
   '</div>';
```

Here, How I find the checkbox `select` by id  and add attribute checked on `changeView()` function?

```
function changeView(m) {                
   //find the select id from content string
  var checkbox = content.find($('#select'+m));
  // Apply the checked property on checkbox.
    checkbox.attr("checked","checked");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't do that... may I ask why do you want to do it

Comment: When you `click` checkbox it will `automatically take care of adding/removing checked`. Why you want to do it programatically?

Comment: @Arun I have Google Map infowindow which return html string.  var content=infowindow.getContent(); I need to make it selected.

Comment: @Murali, This is text of Google Map infowindow html content. It is always refreshed.

Comment: What do you do with the string though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert it to a JQuery object first then you can do it like this:

```
var contentObj = $(content);
var checkbox = contentObj.find("#select");
checkbox.attr("checked", true);
```

then if you need it back at html string:

```
content = contentObj[0].outerHTML;
```

**Note**: If `outerHTML` is not working as expected, the following JQuery can be used as an alternative:

```
content = contentObj.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

---

If `m` is meant to be the `id` you want to find (e.g. "select"), then use this:

```
var checkbox = contentObj.find("#" + m);
```

**Live Example:** [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fuCfA/)

---

Here is the complete function for easy reference:

```
function changeView(m) {
    var contentObj = $(content);
    var checkbox = contentObj.find("#" + m);
    checkbox.attr("checked", true);
    content = contentObj[0].outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: content = contentObj[0].outerHTML; did not back to HTML. I have tested it console.log(content);

Comment: @Masud: In what browser? My example works exactly as described in Chrome

Comment: content remain same on outerHTML. Is it possible to get content with checked <input name="tBox" id="select" type="checkbox" value="" onclick="changeView()" checked=checked>?

Comment: @Masud: It does work! Have you even seen my example? Maybe your version has some scope issues? Post me a JSfiddle that shows it not working (and what browser you are using) and I will tell you what the problem is

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/P2dZP/ I need to retain checkbox selection of Marker infowindow.

Comment: @Masud: That is quite a different situation then your question describes, and unfortunately is beyond my realms of expertise. I would recommend you ask a new question and specific focus on your integration with Google maps. Fully explain what you are trying to do, and what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the string into a DOM object first by wrapping it in a jQuery call first. Then you can use the find method.

So:

```
var dom = $(content),
    select = dom.find('#select');
```

In any case, there is no need to add the 'checked' attribute, because when you click the checkbox, it will automatically become checked.

If however, you want to still programmatically check it:

```
select.on('click', function () {
    this.attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: Suggestion use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` like `this.prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @Satpal: `prop` doesn't actually work in this case, I tried that first. Check out the fiddle from my answer and change it to `prop`, you will see no change in the console output

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this

```
function changeView(m) {                
//find the select id from content string
var checkbox = content.find('#select');
// Apply the checked property on checkbox.
checkbox.attr("checked","checked");
}
```

if you want to pass id  then

```
function changeView(m) {                
//find the select id from content string
var checkbox = content.find("#" + m);
// Apply the checked property on checkbox.
checkbox.attr("checked","checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the onclick handler, you don't really need to do any of that :

in html : `onclick="changeView(this);"`

```
function changeView(box) {
   if(box.checked) { stuff; }
   // or get jquery ref to that box :
   $(box).prop("checked", true);
}
```

Comment: The OP has an HTML string, NOT actual HTML... although the more I read the question the more confusing it gets

Comment: Yeah I'm confused now